# canvas works on desktop perfectly but on mobile doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have canvas functions that work very good on desktop but on mobile it works really weird or doesn't work.

On mobile it works every 20th and only line is drawn when you touch start 50px of the finger.

Here is my code:

```
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
$("#canvas").attr('height', $("#canvasDiv").outerHeight());
$("#canvas").attr('width', $("#canvasDiv").width());
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var blueprint_background = new Image();
blueprint_background.src = srctesting;
blueprint_background.crossOrigin="anonymous";
blueprint_background.onload = function(){
    var pattern = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
    context.rect(0,0,$("#canvasDiv").width(),$("#canvasDiv").outerHeight());
    context.fill();
};

// console.log(blueprint_background)
$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset()
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    paint = true;
    addClick(e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top);
    redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (paint) {
        var offset = $(this).offset()
        //addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
        addClick(e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top, true);
        // console.log(e.pageX, offset.left, e.pageY, offset.top);
        redraw();
    }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e) {
    paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e) {
    paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
    clickX.push(x);
    clickY.push(y);
    clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

$("#reset-btn").click(function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth);
    clickX = [];
    clickY = [];
    clickDrag = [];
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-save', function() {
    var mycanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var img = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    anchor = $("#signature");
    anchor.val(img);
    $("#signatureform").submit(); 
});


var drawing = false;
var mousePos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var lastPos = mousePos;

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
        clientX: touch.clientX,
        clientY: touch.clientY
    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);


canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
    var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
    canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);


canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {

    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var offset = $('#canvas').offset();
    var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
        clientX: touch.clientX,
        clientY: touch.clientY
    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);



// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDiv, touchEvent) {
    var rect = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
        y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
    };
}


var elem = document.getElementById("canvas");

var defaultPrevent = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
elem.addEventListener("touchstart", defaultPrevent);
elem.addEventListener("touchmove", defaultPrevent);


function redraw() {
    //
    lastPos = mousePos;
    for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
        } else {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
        }
        context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have added events for mobile. Am I missing something?

Comment: `var touch = e.changedTouches[0]` might work better ..? You should also check that object exists before referring its properties.

Comment: Hello @Teemu thanks for advice but this didn't fixed the issue

Comment: Ah, my bad, you need to take the last index from `e.changedTouches` , not the first. that miight work also better with `e.touches`.

Comment: @Teemu yes have added var touch = e.touches[e.touches.length-1] but still no improvement , never have worked before with canvas and touch devices.

Comment: Works perfectly fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w79sf6hu/) on a Galaxy S6 on both FF for Android and Chrome.